# Duda al volver a llamar la actividad con un fragment determinado desde la barra de notificaciones

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragment, app, activity

Buenas,

Tengo una aplicación que usa un layout en la `barra de notificaciones`. Dentro del layout, tengo un `botón` con un icono el cual si lo puslo se `abre la aplicación` con la actividad principal.
El problema surge, porque lo que abre es cómo si fuera una actividad nueva, en la cual todo lo que he realizado se pierde. A mi me gustaría que cuando se pulsara el botón, se volviera a abrir lo que ya tenía y se repliegue la barra de notificaciones.

El código del botón es el siguiente:

```
private void openActivity(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(parent, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key", "open"); //Optional parameters
    parent.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Pero cómo ya he dicho antes esto sólo abre la aplicación de 0, sin embargo si yo estoy fuera de la app y pulso el botón del cuadrado que muestra las aplicaciones abiertas y luego pulso en mi app, se abre cómo yo quiero.

Así que `necesito que el botón abra la aplicación que ya está abierta en segundo plano`.

Esta es mi clase para la barra de notificaciones:

```
public class NotificationPanel extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static Context parent;
private static NotificationManager nManager;
private static NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
private static RemoteViews remoteView;
private static RadioOnline radio;
private static final String MyOnClick1 = "IconButton";
private static final String MyOnClick2 = "ButtonStop";
private static final String MyOnClick3 = "ButtonPlay";

public NotificationPanel() {
}

public NotificationPanel(Context parent, RadioOnline radio) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.radio = radio;
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parent)
            .setContentTitle("Radio ECCA")
            .setContentText("Radio Online activada")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setOngoing(true);

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(parent.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);


    setListeners(remoteView);//Llama al método que genera los botones a la escucha.
    nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

    nManager = (NotificationManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());

}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonNbarLogo, getPendingSelfIntent(parent, MyOnClick1));
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnStopNbar, getPendingSelfIntent(parent, MyOnClick2));
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlayNbar, getPendingSelfIntent(parent, MyOnClick3));
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action){
    Intent icon = new Intent(context, getClass());
    icon.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, icon, 0);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (MyOnClick1.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Icono tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked Icon");
        openActivity();
    }else if (MyOnClick2.equals(intent.getAction())){
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Botón Stop tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button stop");
        try {
            pararRadio();
            activarPlay();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else if (MyOnClick3.equals(intent.getAction())){
        //Toast.makeText(context, "Botón Play tocado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button play");
        try {
            if (radio.isNetworkConnectedRemote(parent)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Hay internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                activarStop();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void notificationCancel() {
    nManager.cancel(2);
}

private void pararRadio() throws Exception {
    Log.w("Widget", "Dentro del método pararRadio");

    if (this.radio.getPlayer().isPlaying())
    {
        Log.w("Widget", "Se está reproduciendo");

        try
        {
            this.radio.stopPlaying();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Se ha producido un error al parar el reproductor\n"+e);
        }
    }
}

private void iniciarRadio() throws Exception {
    Log.w("Widget", "Dentro del método pararRadio");

    if (this.radio.getPlayer().isPlaying())
    {
        Log.w("Widget", "Se está reproduciendo");
    }else{
        try
        {
            this.radio.startPlayingRemote();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Se ha producido un error al inicializar el reproductor\n"+e);
        }
    }
}

private void activarPlay(){
    Resources res = parent.getResources();
    String mystring = res.getString(R.string.infoNbarStoped);
    this.remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnStopNbar, View.INVISIBLE);
    this.remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPlayNbar, View.VISIBLE);
    //this.remoteView.setBoolean(R.id.btnPlayNbar, "setEnabled", true);
    this.remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.messageNbar, mystring);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
}

private void activarStop(){
    Resources res = parent.getResources();
    String mystring = res.getString(R.string.infoNbar);
    this.remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnStopNbar, View.VISIBLE);
    this.remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.btnPlayNbar, View.INVISIBLE);
    //this.remoteView.setBoolean(R.id.btnPlayNbar, "setEnabled", true);
    this.remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.messageNbar, mystring);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
}

private void openActivity(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(parent, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key", "open"); //Optional parameters
    parent.startActivity(myIntent);
}
}
```

Un saludo, estoy aprendiendo mucho con ustedes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se como estés creando tu notificación, pero en mi caso estoy usando un Servicio en android para crear la notificación. Los intents se utilizan para cambiar de actividad y crean siempre la actividad desde cero, algo que puedes intentar es enviarle los parametros necesarios para continuar donde estabas. Por ejemplo si estoy creando un reproductor de música, desde el botón de la notificacion puedo mandarle los parámetros siguientes: la cancion que se está reproduciendo, el nombre del artista y el tiempo actual de la cancion en reproducción.

```
private void openActivity(){
Intent myIntent = new Intent(parent, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", "open"); //Optional parameters
myIntent.putExtra("someParameter","song Parameter"); //parameters that you need
parent.startActivity(myIntent);
```

}

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @HRaulGutierrezC, he puesto el código entero de mi clase que genera la notificación. Cómo bien dices los intents crean siempre la actividad, entonces lo estoy haciendo mal. Ya que mi intención es que no se cree una actividad nueva sino que se abra la que está en segundo plano. Sería la misma función que cuando se pulsa el botón cuadrado de las aplicaciones abiertas de android y se seleccionara la mía. No se si me he explicado bien. De nuevo te doy las gracias por tomar tu tiempo para contestarme.

Comment: @Natlum creo que esta documentacion de android te puede servir (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=es-419)

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a estudiarme bien eso para poder sacarlo. Cuando lo encuentre podré la solución aquí para que otros aprendan cómo yo.

Answer (score 0):

En el manifiesto ponerle a la activity: android:launchMode="singleInstance"